# Oracle Editioning Views and JPA or Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, jpa

My application uses WAS 7 and Oracle 11g. I'm looking forward to achieve zero downtime during deployments. The deployment involves EAR deployments to WAS and DDL/DML changes to Oracle DB. This question focuses on no downtime for Oracle DB during DDL/DML upgrade and supporting new data definition in Java EE application.

One of the team here has achieved this using Oracle Editioning Views (Edition based revision) layer for each table. However my application uses JPA and Hibernate. I've conducted a small PoC to create entities for Editioning Views; however it seems JPA or Hibernate does not support them.

Is there any information available about using Editioning Views with JPA or Hibernate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you look at Liquibase this will allow the application to keep its own database uptodate.

If you use spring it's very easy, you just need a spring bean like :

```
@Bean
public SpringLiquibase liquibase() {
    log.debug("Configuring Liquibase");
    SpringLiquibase liquibase = new SpringLiquibase();
    liquibase.setDataSource(dataSource());
    liquibase.setChangeLog("classpath:config/liquibase/master.xml");
    liquibase.setContexts("development, production");
    return liquibase;
}
```

Then you have a change log:

```
databaseChangeLog
  xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog
         http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.1.xsd">

    <changeSet id="1" author="bob">
        <createTable tableName="department">
            <column name="id" type="int">
                <constraints primaryKey="true" nullable="false"/>
            </column>
            <column name="name" type="varchar(50)">
                <constraints nullable="false"/>
            </column>
            <column name="active" type="boolean" defaultValueBoolean="true"/>
        </createTable>
    </changeSet>

</databaseChangeLog>
```

Each time the application starts it will check if there are any changes which need applying.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I've never tried Liquibase. Will do some PoC to see how it helps.

Answer (score 1):

One way to go is using partitioned tables for main data table and a staging table for changes. You make the changes  the staging table and then the swap using:

```
ALTER TABLE main_table
EXCHANGE PARTITION main_table_1001 WITH TABLE staging_table
WITHOUT VALIDATION
UPDATE GLOBAL INDEXES;
```

This way, your client(i.e. java web app) wont even notice the changes happening in the backend.